# What is the difference between Ember and Blaze server/client implementations?

Tags: scala, http4s

I could not find any information on what http4s server/client implementation to choose, Ember or Blaze What is better and why. What are the key differences between them? Maybe someone from the creators of the http4s could answer this.

Comment: **blaze** is older, and less likely to have missing features or bugs, but is a wrapper over `Futures`. - **ember** is newer, written from scratch based on **cats-effect** and **fs2** primitives, and has more active development right now, but may have some bugs / missing features. - Personally, I use **ember** since I haven't had any major issues that weren't already fixed.